# Checking if model weights have changed in tensorflow?

Tags: python, list, numpy, tensorflow

I'm training a Generative Adversarial Network now and I have a bad feeling that weights are being updated in a way they shouldn't so I am trying to change it. But because of arrays and mutability, I can't check properly with the `np.array_equal()` function.

My code pipeline looks a little like:

```
gen_1=gen.trainable_variables
disc_1=disc.trainable_variables
disc.train_on_batch()#train discriminator
disc_2=disc.trainable_variables #to get values after weight update
```

But since these are mutable arrays, I think disc_1 and disc_2 are pointing to the same value. `np.copy()` fails since `model.trainable_variables` returns a sequence and not an array

What could I realistically do to solve this issue?

Comment: if they points to the same value then they didn't change. if you get sequences then you should  try to compare sequences

Comment: I'm not sure that is true.

I tried something similar

```value=[1,2,3,4,5]
X=value
for i range(len(value)):
 value[i]+=1
y=value
print(value, X,y)
```

Then they are all [2,3,4,5]

Comment: @furas I just checked object IDs, no new object is created, so disc_1 and disc_2 are pointing to the same object and so they don't store different values.